# What is the purpose of LINQ's Expression.Quote method?

Tags: linq, expression, linq-expressions

The MSDN documentation states:

> **Expression.Quote**
>
> Method Creates a
>   UnaryExpression that represents an
>   expression that has a constant value
>   of type Expression.

I've been able to build predicate expressions for use in LINQ queries by manually constructing them using the Expression class, but have never come across the need for Expression.Quote.

When and why would you use this? From the LINQ expressions I've seen that have them, they just seem to wrap existing expressions without adding any value.

What is the purpose of the Quote method/node type?

Comment: "When you are constructing a MethodCallExpression using Expression.Call, any parameters that are lambda expressions (LambdaExpression/Expression<TDelegate>) must use Expression.Quote to wrap the parameter before passing in."  Is that true? Using .Net 4.5, I'm able to successfully pass bare Expression<Func<>> without needing to first quote them with Expression.Quote().

Comment: If your parameter is of type `Func<>`, then sure that is all you need, but in the case of many LINQ `IQueryable<T>` extension methods, the parameter type is actually `Expression<Func<>>`, and in that case you will need `Expression.Quote`. I haven't tried doing this with .NET 4.5, but I'd assume it was the same. At the time of writing I was probably using .NET 3.5.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`Expression.Quote` specifies that a lambda is to be treated as an expression tree and not as a function. It induces closure semantics on its operand.

When you are constructing a `MethodCallExpression` using `Expression.Call`, any parameters that are lambda expressions (`LambdaExpression`/`Expression<TDelegate>`) must use `Expression.Quote` to wrap the parameter before passing in.

So for a parameter of type `Expression<Func<bool>>`, when you create an instance such as: `() => true`, the expression's `Type` property would be `Func<bool>` whereas the expression's type (calling `GetType`) would be `Expression<Func<bool>>`

So to get an `Expression` that has the correct value for the `Type` property you pass the lambda expression into `Expression.Quote` and pass that as the parameter to `Expression.Call`.

I had a look at `Expression.Quote` through reflector and while the sole parameter is of type `Expression`, it must derive from `LambdaExpression` and this is checked inside the method. Out of interest, anyone know why MS didn't just make the parameter type be `LambdaExpression`?

As StevenH pointed out, `Expression.Quote` is used in implementing LINQ Query Providers. All the methods on `Queryable` that take a lambda expression such as `Where`, `OrderBy`, `GroupBy`, etc internally construct a `MethodCallExpression` using `Expression.Call` and wrap the lambda expression parameters with `Expression.Quote` calls.

For a more detailed explanation of `Expression.Quote` read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3753382/80282).