# If an identity conversion exists from S to T, must it be that S and T are same type?

Tags: c#, language-specifications

In 6.1.6. of the C# language specification, there is:

> The implicit reference conversions are:
>
> (...)
>   From any reference-type to a reference-type T if it has an implicit identity or reference conversion to a reference-type T0 and T0 has an identity conversion to T.

Why don't they say instead, more simply:

> From any reference-type to a reference-type T if it has an implicit identity or reference conversion to T.

Is there any factual difference?

EDIT: I realized I mistyped the specification and the error could potentially be significant for the question (the specification says "The implicit reference conversion are" rather than "An implicit  conversion exists")

Comment: "reference conversion to T0 AND  T0 has an identity conversion to T.".. sounds like there is a difference.

Comment: I think the last part could be important. As type `T` could implicitly convert to type `U` due to its implicit identity or reference conversion to `U`. However `U` *may not* necessarily have an identity conversion to `U`.  It doesn't mention `U` having a reference conversion to `T` though... confuzzed.

Comment: @LewsTherin It sounds like that, sure, but what is it? I'm confused why the "middle-man" T0 is necessary. By my reading, all types have an identity conversion to themselves and no type has an identity conversion to any other type.

Comment: I won't pretend to understand this shiz. 
But I just found this.. might help: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736789/question-regarding-implicit-conversions-in-the-c-sharp-language-specification

Comment: I think you mistake the *and*, it should be (from S to T0) AND (from T0 to T). So if S can be converted to T0 and T0 to T then S can be converted to T.

Comment: @Dirk Like transitivity? if a is b and b is c then a is c?

Comment: @Lews Therin that's how I understand it, except that is slightly more complicated because from S to T0 is a reference conversion and from T0 to T an indentity conversion.

Comment: S to T0 can be an identity or reference conversion.. so I guess the confusion starts when S to T0 has no identity conversion but only reference conversion. Maybe the spec should first define what "identity conversion" and "reference conversion" is.

Comment: I think you need it to convert `Derived<dynamic>` to `Base<object>`.

Comment: @LewsTherin: I think you'll find that the spec does define both those things.

Comment: @EricLippert I was able to find one for "reference conversion" not identity conversion though.

Comment: @LewsTherin: Consider looking in the table of contents.

Comment: @EricLippert I did find that. But it is over complicated. 
"An identity conversion converts from any type to the same type. This conversion exists such that an entity that already has a required type can be said to be convertible to that type." 
"Same type", "that type" means little to me.  I like your explanation better though.

Comment: @LewsTherin: The specification does not even define "type". It's not intended to be a formal description of the type system; you won't find any Hoare logic in the specification.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> If an identity conversion exists from S to T, must it be that S and T are same type?

The oddity you've discovered in the spec arose as a result of adding `dynamic` to the language in C# 4.0. At runtime there is no such thing as `dynamic`; rather, `dynamic` is just a type that means "I'm really `object`; please defer analysis of this portion of the program until runtime".

Therefore there is an *identity conversion* between, say, `List<object>` and `List<dynamic>`.  From the C# compiler's perspective they are different types because `myList[0].Frob()` would give an error for the former but not the latter. But from the runtime's perspective they are identical. Therefore the C# language classifies the conversion from one to the other as an identity conversion. At compile time the types can be different for the purposes of the C# language, but from the runtime's perspective they will be identical.