# What exactly is the Identity Conversion in C#?

Tags: c#

It is not clear what exactly is Identity Conversion in `C#`. Microsoft says:

> Identity conversion An identity conversion converts from any type to
> the same type. This conversion exists such that an entity that already
> has a required type can be said to be convertible to that type.
>
> Because object and dynamic are considered equivalent there is an
> identity conversion between object and dynamic, and between
> constructed types that are the same when replacing all occurrences of
> dynamic with object.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/conversions

It would be nice to see some examples in C# of such conversion with some custom types to understand what exactly it is, its limitations, and benefits comparing to other types of conversions.

Comment: It's just converting to itself. https://csharp.2000things.com/tag/identity-conversion/

Comment: I think this answer of @EricLippert can give more information https://stackoverflow.com/a/20935857/3206146

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As stated in the quote in the question, it's just the conversion of type X to itself. I.e.,

```
string x = (string) "Hello";
```

[or even just](https://csharp.2000things.com/tag/identity-conversion/):

```
string x = "Hello";
```

It's essentially just a no-op conversion.

As noted, "This conversion exists such that an entity that already has a required type can be said to be convertible to that type." So essentially the justification the spec gives is that it makes it easier to write the spec; the writers can say "such-and-such expression X is implicitly converted to type Y" even if X is already Y.

As Andrew's answer notes, [there's a special case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935319/if-an-identity-conversion-exists-from-s-to-t-must-it-be-that-s-and-t-are-same-t/20935857#20935857) with `object` and `dynamic`, as the latter is actually `object` at runtime.

(This answer originally noted the rationale from a similar language, Java, but I felt it was incomplete and the same things could be said about C# just based on the C# specification.)

Answer (score 3):

If you want, for example, convert `dynamic` to `object` compiler will use an *identity conversion* to do that. From the compiler perspective, there is a difference between `object` and `dynamic`. But from the runtime perspective, they are exactly the same.

In other words, from the compiler perspective, you need *conversion* in this case, but this conversion is possible because these types are actually *identical*.

You can also look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20935857/3206146) of Eric Lippert to another question.