# What I get from UnaryExpression.Operand?

Tags: c#, expression

I'm reading code abour how to [building an IQueryable Provider](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mattwar/2008/11/18/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-series/)

Below is code fragment

```
internal class QueryTranslator : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        .....
        private static Expression StripQuotes(Expression e)
        {
            while (e.NodeType == ExpressionType.Quote)
            {
                e = ((UnaryExpression)e).Operand;
            }
            return e;
        }
        protected override Expression VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression m)
        {
            if (m.Method.DeclaringType == typeof(Queryable))
            {
                if (m.Method.Name == "Where")
                {
                    sb.Append("SELECT * FROM (");
                    this.Visit(m.Arguments[0]);
                    sb.Append(") AS T WHERE ");
                    LambdaExpression lambda = (LambdaExpression)StripQuotes(m.Arguments[1]);
                    this.Visit(lambda.Body);
                    return m;
                }
                else if (m.Method.Name == "Select")
                {
                    LambdaExpression lambda = (LambdaExpression)StripQuotes(m.Arguments[1]);
                    ColumnProjection projection = new ColumnProjector().ProjectColumns(lambda.Body, this.row);
                    sb.Append("SELECT ");
                    sb.Append(projection.Columns);
                    sb.Append(" FROM (");
                    this.Visit(m.Arguments[0]);
                    sb.Append(") AS T ");
                    this.projection = projection;
                    return m;
                }
            }
            throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("The method '{0}' is not supported", m.Method.Name));
        }
        .....
    }
```

I can't understand method StripQuotes, What I get from e = ((UnaryExpression)e).Operand ?

Comment: The operand is the value given to the operator so for example if i do `!false` the operand is `false` meanwhile the operator is `!`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What does Expression.Quote() do that Expression.Constant() can’t already do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716492/what-does-expression-quote-do-that-expression-constant-can-t-already-do) explains what `Quote` does.

The question now is when would the `Quote` operation be encountered in a real-world scenario by a LINQ provider. It appears when you invoke `IQueryable` operations that take expression trees as arguments. For example, `bool Queryable.Where(IQueryable inputQuery, Expression<Func<..., bool>> predicate)` takes an expression tree.

If you say `myQueryable.Where(x => ...)` the C# compiler will generate `Expression.*` invocations to build that expression tree and pass that to `Where`. No `Quote` here.

But if the expression tree generation is *nested* then `Quote` is used:

```
myQueryable.Where(x => x.SomeCollection.Any(y => ...))
```

Here, the `y => ...` part is of type `Expression<..., bool>`. This requires `Quote`.

I believe a simple LINQ provider can just unwrap/discard the `Quote` and generate code as if it didn't exist. If you want to be totally correct you'd need special handling of that case in the LINQ provider. The LINQ provider code in the question is "demo code" quality so it does not do that.

You can use `https://sharplab.io/` to play with different kinds of query to see what the compiler generates. E.g.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class C {
    public void M2() {
        var query =
            new SomeClass[0]
            .AsQueryable()
            .Where(x => x.SomeCollection.Any(y => y % 2 == 0));
    }
    static bool F(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<int, bool>> e) { return true; }

    class SomeClass {
        public IQueryable<int> SomeCollection { get; set; }
    }
}
```

https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAbgLAChYMQOgDICWAdgI5roZQDMCATHAMJwDeGc7CNUALHALK0AFAEoWbDhIBuAQwBOcEgFcAprICecALziJuuEWUB3OAGUA9gFtlDADbSAzvYDaMALo69HHAEF7ARRV1aQAjG2URD084HAB1AAtVcIAPLQA+OCSccysGMxswgGMAFwIzIh8iNUENTXSNAFI4ek1NOBhhYXIJAF8PJAA2OGCzPLgAMUEkfGISHABRJIAHWWVHUqJ7eaWVtbKAHigAVj3iIoAaIZGbVPTlUWYEAHY4ItkVZDhe9Ak++mzrOyOMTfTzUOAASQCqjUITCJyIRXS/1y+WUxXWLDgAHNlEUPvZcR8vj0MF8gA