# why UnaryExpression not have body

Tags: linq, expression, expression-trees

I was seeking some information about how to use Expression.Quote. And I've found an answer for it, [What is the purpose of LINQ's Expression.Quote method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138133/what-is-the-purpose-of-linqs-expression-quote-method)

After reading the post, I know how to use Expression.Quote and its effects. But in this post, you can see that the UnaryExpression class has a Body property. But now, I can't find it in VS2010 and in MSDN too. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UnaryExpression` class does not have a `Body` property. If you look closely in the screenshot you are referring to, you'll see that the `Body` property is actually seen under the `UnaryExpression.Operand` property, and is therefore actually on the [`LambdaExpression`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression.body.aspx) class.